# File written 3 times C#

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have this code that is being repeated 3 times:

```
private static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
{
    string FileName;
    FileName = f.FullPath;

    string destinationFile = @"Y:\test\test.xml";
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
   try
   {

        Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);
        Encoding ansi = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        string xml = File.ReadAllText(FileName, ansi);
       XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            **Console.WriteLine("1st");**
            File.WriteAllText(
               destinationFile,
                @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" + xmlDoc.ToString(),
               utf8
            );
    }
```

Check the above in bold. It writes out 3 times. I have just put that to test. But why does it write out 3 times.. Meaning the file being written is also written 3 times.

I'm calling this function from a filesystemwatcher function to watch a folder if it has changed then take the file convert it to utf-8 and put it in the destination file.

EDIT 1:
Here is my watcher. Can you please check if this is fine:

```
private static void WatchFile()
    {
                watcher.Path = @"C:\project";

                   watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.xml";


        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(convert);
        watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(WatcherError);
        Console.WriteLine("2nd");
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


    }
```

Still don't have a clue why it gets repeated 3 times.

EDIT 2:

Here goes' my complete code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;





class Test
{
 class Class1
{
    private static FileSystemWatcher watcher =
       new FileSystemWatcher();

    public static void Main()
    {
        WatchFile();
      Console.ReadLine();
     }

    private static void WatchFile()
    {
        watcher.Path = @"C:\project";

                    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.xml";


        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(convert);
        watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(WatcherError);
        Console.WriteLine("2nd");
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }

    public static string CrL = "\r\n";

    private static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
    {
        string FileName;
        FileName = f.FullPath;

               string destinationFile = @"Y:\test\OnAirNow.xml";

                 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
       try
       {

            Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            Encoding ansi = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FileName, ansi);
           XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                Console.WriteLine("1st");
                File.WriteAllText(
                   destinationFile,
                    @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" + xmlDoc.ToString(),
                   utf8
                );



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }


    }

    private static void WatcherError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {

        Exception watchException = e.GetException();
                   watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        while (!watcher.EnableRaisingEvents)
        {
            try
            {
                                   WatchFile();
                Console.WriteLine("I'm Back!!");
            }
            catch
            {
                                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }


  }  
 }
```

Comment: Most probably the function `convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)` is called several times by the filesystemwatcher function. If you give us a little more code about the file watcher we will be more helpful probably.

Comment: There's no looping in this method, so the problem isn't here. The problem will be in the code that calls this method (multiple FSW events firing?)

Comment: I would agree, i have seen before that an edit to a file has triggered a delete and a create call on a file thus resulting in two calls

Comment: Yes, this is not guaranteed by the framework

Comment: It is actually not quaranteed by the application USING the file. Depending how the edit is done that may be a delete / recreate (rename, recreate).

Comment: I have edited with my watcher. Can you please check if this is fine

Comment: Edited is my complete code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common pattern using `FileSystemWatcher` is to set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `false` when starting processing the event:

```
this.fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher()
{
    Path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
    Filter = Path.GetFileName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile)
};

this.fileSystemWatcher.Changed += this.ConfigChanged;
this.fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

and

```
public void ConfigChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        s_logger.Info("Configuration file changed.");
        // reload config here
        s_logger.Info("Configuration settings reloaded.");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        s_logger.Error(exception.Message);
        s_logger.Error("Failed to reload configuration settings.");
    }
    finally
    {
        this.fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this works perfectly. It doesn't repeat by using this method.. Nice one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The FileSystemWatcher might raise more than one event for one file change, check it out:

> Common file system operations might raise more than one event. For example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised. Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple operations, therefore raising multiple events. Likewise, some applications (for example, antivirus software) might cause additional file system events that are detected by FileSystemWatcher.

[FileSystemWatcher Class in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have edited the above with my watcher. So please check if my watcheer is fine.